# Prestashop getPackageShippingCost() modification

Tags: overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm working on a PRESTASHOP override option,
i need to update the function getPackageShippingCost() in override/classes/Cart.php
i want prestashop to take this overide into consideration only if my id_carrier is 5 for example, is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can easily do it like this:

```php
class Cart extends CartCore
{

    public function getPackageShippingCost($id_carrier = null, $use_tax = true, Country $default_country = null, $product_list = null, $id_zone = null)
    {

        if ($id_carrier !== 5)
        {
            return parent::getPackageShippingCost($id_carrier, $use_tax, $default_country, $product_list, $id_zone);
        }

        // YOUR CUSTOM CODE
    }
}
```

Do not forget to remove file `/cache/class_index.php` after adding a new override.